# Handle character arrays that include spaces

Tags: c, arrays, io, char, spaces

I'm working on a program that has you enter your name, and the program then puts it into a square.  For example, for the input `"Zyad"` I would expect the output:

```
 ********
|        |
|  Zyad  |
|        |
 ********
```

Now I want to be able to enter two names (for example first and last name) and get the same sort of output.

The input of `"Zyad Sabry"` would yield

```
 **************
|              |
|  Zyad Sabry  |
|              |
 **************
```

My Code :

```
scanf("%s",name);
n = strlen(name);
printf(" ");

for(i=0;i<n+4;i++)
    printf("*");
    printf("\n");
    printf("|");

    for(i=0;i<n+4;i++)
        printf(" ");
        printf("|");

    printf("\n");
    printf("|");

    for(i=0;i<(n+4)-n-2;i++)
        printf(" ");
        printf("%s  |");

    printf("\n");
    printf("|");

    for(i=0;i<n+4;i++)
        printf(" ");
        printf("|");

    printf("\n");
    printf(" ");

    for(i=0;i<n+4;i++)
        printf("*");
```

Comment: What do you mean can't understand?

Comment: Your question doesn't show effort at all. You're supposed to show some code that you tried and isn't working.

Comment: The program you made to treat with a single name may work with only a slight modification with two names. Just show your code here and we'll be able to tell you.

Comment: `char name[64]; scanf("%63[^\n]", name);`

Comment: Sorry man forgot to paste the code 
@JoëlHecht
NOTE  : Posted now :D

Comment: Sorry man forgot to paste the code @Tudor NOTE : Posted now :D

Comment: You Rock Man !! Thankss ;) @BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 0):

when you have a character array as follows

```
char name[500];
```

You can take input a string that contains any character except `\n` as follows

```
int i;
for(i=0;(name[i]=getchar())!='\n';i++);
name[i]='\0';  //null termination
```

Assuming that the length of the array is enough to store the name.